# How to display 8-bit icons in Windows Installer?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I have a number of .ico files in my installer that have various renderings for different palette depths, sizes, etc.  These display on the MSI's UI rather than being a part of the installation process.

Unfortunately, each of these icon files are displaying the 4-bit palette depth version, which looks a bit rubbish.  Is there a way to get the icons to display at the full 8-bit palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8-bit icons are unsupported in Windows Installer.  I got around the problem by having the 4-bit icons re-drawn so they looked better in the lower colour palette.

Answer (score 0):

Why not delete the 4 bit version from the icon and keep only the 8 bit one version?

Comment: I thought the 4-bit icon is displaying because 8-bit palette icons aren't supported; is this not the case?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I really don't know, I saw some cases when the 1st ico was loaded no matter what, so if the 1st ico is going to be 8 bpp it might work around the problem.

Comment: Just got another chance to look at this.  The first image in the icon file is an 8bpp image, whilst the 4bpp image that is being displayed is the sixth.